# How can I filter Bootstrap cards with the use of a button?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-5

how would I go about filtering cards with the click of a button?

I'd want to create a function in java script and link it to the button, but I'm not sure on how I'd filter the cards through this method.

Say I click the Museum button, I want all cards that feature Museum to stay and all cards that don't to disappear.

Thanks for any help.

(HTML could use some brushing up but it's only a mock up so far)

```html
<div class="buttons">
  <h2><b>Choices:</b></h2>
  <button onclick="blank()">Clear</button>
  <button onclick="">Museums</button>
  <button onclick="">Bars</button>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 space-top">
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
      <img src="img/sher.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="sher">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Sheridans</h5>
        <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go here</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 space-top">
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
      <img src="img/mus.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="mus">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Museum</h5>
        <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go here</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 space-top">
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
      <img src="img/dock.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="dock">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Docks</h5>
        <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go here</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- end Rows -->
</div>
<!-- end Container -->
<script src="js/Cho_script.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the easiest way is to just add a class to each of your cards, either museum or notMuseum and then grab the notMuseum cards.  Alternatively you can grab all cards and then filter based on the content of card-title but that seems more complicated.

```js
const toggleThese = document.getElementsByClassName('notMuseum')
for (let i = 0; i < toggleThese.length; i++) {
  toggleThese[i].style.display = 'block'
}

function toggleMe() {
  for (let i = 0; i < toggleThese.length; i++) {
    if (toggleThese[i].style.display == 'block') {
      toggleThese[i].style.display = 'none'
    } else {
      toggleThese[i].style.display = 'block'
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
  <h2><b>Choices:</b></h2>
  <button onclick="blank()">Clear</button>
  <button onclick="toggleMe()">Museums</button>
  <button onclick="">Bars</button>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 space-top">
    <div class="card notMuseum" style="width: 18rem;">
      <img src="img/sher.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="sher">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Sheridans</h5>
        <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go here</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 space-top">
    <div class="card Museum" style="width: 18rem;">
      <img src="img/mus.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="mus">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Museum</h5>
        <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go here</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 space-top">
    <div class="card notMuseum" style="width: 18rem;">
      <img src="img/dock.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="dock">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Docks</h5>
        <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go here</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- end Rows -->
</div>
<!-- end Container -->
<script src="js/Cho_script.js"></script>
```

And here's how to do it using filter:

```js
const cardObjects = document.getElementsByClassName('card')
var cardArray = Object.values(cardObjects)


function checkMuseum(item) {
  const cardTitle = item.getElementsByClassName('card-title')[0]  
  if (cardTitle.textContent != 'Museum')return item;
}

function myFunction() {  
  var notMuseum = cardArray.filter(checkMuseum);  
  for(let i = 0; i<notMuseum.length;i++){  
      if(notMuseum[i].style.display == ''|| notMuseum[i].style.display=='block'){ 
          notMuseum[i].style.display='none';
      }else{
          notMuseum[i].style.display='block';
      }
   } 
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
  <h2><b>Choices:</b></h2>
  <button onclick="blank()">Clear</button>
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Museums</button>
  <button onclick="">Bars</button>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 space-top">
    <div class="card notMuseum" style="width: 18rem;">
      <img src="img/sher.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="sher">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Sheridans</h5>
        <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go here</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 space-top">
    <div class="card Museum" style="width: 18rem;">
      <img src="img/mus.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="mus">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Museum</h5>
        <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go here</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 space-top">
    <div class="card notMuseum" style="width: 18rem;">
      <img src="img/dock.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="dock">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Docks</h5>
        <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go here</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- end Rows -->
</div>
<!-- end Container -->
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I appreciate this a lot.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be to add/remove the Bootstrap `d-none` class...

```
<button onclick="clearAll()">Clear</button>
<button onclick="filter('Museum')">Museums</button>
<button onclick="filter('Bar')">Bars</button>


var filter = (filter) => {
    const cards = document.getElementsByClassName("col-sm-12");
    for (let i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
        let title = cards[i].querySelector(".card .card-body .card-title");
        if (title.innerText.indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            cards[i].classList.remove("d-none")
        } else {
            cards[i].classList.add("d-none")
        }
    }
}

var clearAll = () => {
    cards = document.getElementsByClassName("col-sm-12")
    for (i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
        cards[i].classList.remove("d-none")
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/hDumu8C5Oz)

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful!

Comment: Mark it accepted so others know the question is solved